# Upgrade to Windows 8.1 pro using kms?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I have WINDOWS 8.1 Single language OEM version. I want update it to windows 8.1 pro, which the university provides via KMS. What is the command to upgrade it to windows 8.1 pro?

Comment: You would first have to upgrade the installation, then activate the license, per your university's instructions.

Comment: **Dism /online /Set-Edition:Professional /AcceptEula**. After the upgrade, apply the KMS key + KMS settings and activate Windows.

Comment: You do understand by upgrading to this license, at any point you are not a student, the school can basically deactivate your installation.  You are losing a lot of rights by doing the upgrade basically.